# How to retrieve JSONobject response specific value in Android

Tags: android, json

I want to store a particular value of JSONobject response in one variable.
My JSON response is a string:

```
{"username":"admin","password":"admin","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"}
```

And from this response I want to retrieve the mobile number.

Can Anyone help?

Comment: what you tried so far ?

Comment: I have recieved a response from server in json format as sring {username":"admin","password":"admin","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"} and now i want to retrive one specific key. 
and for this i have used jsonobject

Answer (score 1):

Your Json is

> {"username":"admin","password":"admin","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"}

**Parse it Easily**

```
 JSONObject jsonObject= new JSONObject(json_response);
 String mobile= jsonObject.optString("mobile");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use asynchttpclient library. Its easy to use and parse values.

add this line in app gradle,

```
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
```

Then,

```
Let, String s = "{"username":"admin","password":"admin","mobile":"xxxxxxxxxx"}";

JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(s);
String username = jsonObject.optString("username");
String mobile = jsonObject.optString("mobile");
String password = jsonObject.optString("password");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do something like the below:

```
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
if (jsonObject.length() > 0) {
 String mobile  = jsonObject.optString("mobile");
 Log.e("TAG", "mobile:"+mobile);
}
```